# How to select the list based on its dynamic value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I am new in knockout.i want that when i click on edit button based on the value the dropdown should be selected.

Here is My Full Code...I am trying to Edit the Record...

Here is My HTML Code

Here is my JS code...

function item(id, name) 
{
        this.id = ko.observable(id);

```
    this.name1 = ko.observable(name);
```

}

function CompanyViewModel()
{

var self = this;
        var Sort = "desc";

```
    self.id = ko.observable("");
    self.name = ko.observable().extend
```

({
            required: true
        });
        self.bloombergcode = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });

```
    self.Id = ko.observable();

    self.sector1 = [new item(1, "Banking"), new item(2, "Non-Banking")];

    self.country = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.sectorid = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });

    self.isincode = ko.observable();
enter code here
    self.address = ko.observable();

    this.validationModel = ko.validatedObservable({
        name: self.name,
        bloombergcode: self.bloombergcode,
        sectorid: self.sectorid

    });



    //        self.items = ko.observableArray([]);
    var company =
{
    id: self.id,
    name: self.name,
    bloombergcode: self.bloombergcode,
    sectorid: self.sectorid,
    isincode: self.isincode,
    sector1: self.sector1,
    address: self.address
};

    self.company = ko.observable();
    self.companies = ko.observableArray();


    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("CompanyId", "Company")',
        cache: false,
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {

            //self.companies(data);
            self.company(data); 

            self.id(data.id);

            self.name(data.name);

            self.sectorid = ko.observable(new item(data.sectorid, ""));

            self.isincode(data.isincode);

            self.address(data.address);

            self.sectorid(self.sector1[1].id);

           // self.sectorid(self.sector1[1]);


            self.bloombergcode(data.bloombergcode)
        }
    });
```

}

var viewModel=new CompanyViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

Comment: Any progress with this issue? Have you tried to implement my solution? Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Your HTML code is missing and your code is really hard to read because some of the code is outside of the code regions. Please have considerations for those of us who are trying to help you solve your problems. A little more effort would be appreciated.

Comment: My Html code is complete...and only the one function is outsid.Please tell me what kind of effort you expected from me...?

Comment: Please some one help me...

Answer (score 0):

Since you supplied the `optionsValue` parameter, you need to set `sectored` to the `id` value. In other words:

```
self.sectorid(self.sector[1].id());
```

Also, your binding statement is incorrect. You're missing quotes around `id` on the `optionsValue` parameter. Such as:

```
<select id="sector" data-bind="options:sector1 , validationElement: sectorid, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', optionsValue:'id', optionsCaption: '........Select........', value: $root.sectorid, optionsText: 'name1' "></select>
```

Hope that helps!

P.S. For clarification, without supplying the `optionsValue`, knockout will use the actual object as the value. In that case, the code you had originally, `self.sectorid(self.sector[1])` would have worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the help...but its still not working...
and its self.sectorid(self.sector1[1].id);

Comment: See the correction to the binding statement in the edited answer above.

Comment: I found an issue in my answer. I was missing the execution of the `id` observable. See if the updated answer doesn't do it for you.

Comment: If that still doesn't fix it, can you update your post with the current state of your JS code and HTML? From what I can tell, it should be working but I'd like to see your code to see if I can spot any errors.